# How do map providers collect/update street names in the Middle East?

Tags: data, streets, address, middle-east

Spatial data in Middle eastern countries, is not as comprehensive as it is in European countries or the United States.

How do map providers/producers get street names, update new areas and all of these related things?

Do they have an agent or similar to provide them with the data ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Middle_East_countries_by_population) there are 16 Middle East countries and I suspect that how this is done will vary between them.  Consequently, to better fit our focussed Q&A format, would you be able to revise your question to just refer to the Middle East country which is the most for you to have this information, please?  You can always research/ask about the others separately.